# KDE - Global Menu - Dual Screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, kde, plasma-5, globalmenu

Hello askubuntu Community,

I use a Plasma 5.21 setup that includes a global menu sitting in a topbar. It works perfectly fine, except when I move a window to the second screen. When I do that the menu just disapears. Is there a way to show the menu of a focused application, runing on the second screen, on the global menu of the main screen?

I'm glad for every help!